# HVAC - noisy preheat

Tags: hvac, heating, heater, central-heating, natural-gas

When the heat comes on I hear a noticeably loud whirring sound in the beginning. It only lasts for a couple minutes and then quiets down while the fan continues to blow heat throughout the home. I have a natural gas furnace and have attached a video of the sound being made.

How should I troubleshoot this further?

https://youtu.be/jprZ46uhQxY

**--EDIT--**

Someone pointed out it is most likely the draft induction motor and I'm currently looking for a replacement.

Comment: Please revise to at least tell us what _type_ of device we're discussing, if for some reason you can't list the make and model. It's on you to determine what type of fuel it's consuming. Surely you know what you pay for in your energy bill. Don't make us to watch YouTube to figure these things out.

Comment: My _brand new_ NG furnace does exactly the same thing, as did the 25 year old unit it replaced which did that for all 25 heating seasons it was installed. This is completely normal behavior. Of course, if your furnace is _not_ NG powered, then it could be darn near anything. If you don't know how to tell if you've got NG, propane, electric, heating oil, coal or another heating system, I'd suggest you call in a professional to check it out for your own safety.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks for posting a comment - to answer your question my furnace is verified natural gas

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks for the commentary. The noise won't be as concerning now that I know it's the draft inducer motor doing its job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My natural gas heating unit runs almost silent normally, but it started sounding similar last year when the draft inducer motor was failing. The draft inducer is an exhaust fan that starts up and makes sure it can pull the combustion byproducts out the vent stack before the gas starts up in a heating cycle.

I was able to identify it was this motor by pulling off the front panel and checking where the vibration came from when this noise was active. Pushing on the motor made most of the noise go away, but the mounting bolts were already tight and so was the seal. The draft inducer is a large spiral shape with a motor in the middle.

[image]

These have labels on them and also model numbers molded into the plastic. You should be able to look it up and replace it with the same or compatible unit. Typically the hardest part is wiring the motor but they use wiring harnesses that clip together, just route the wires properly.

And it should go without saying, but make sure the breakers for the heater are shut off before you start, because if the thermostat calls for heat while you're working, "you're gonna have a bad time."

Comment: Thanks @FredricShope ! So you replaced yours and that made it quieter? I'm curious if you think it's payout is worth the effort.

Comment: Replacing it only makes it quieter if it's failing, and if it's failing it'll likely prevent the furnace from starting. Whether  it's _worth it_ is up to you.

Comment: I edited to clarify that yes it was failing (it started making the noise after running mostly silent for a long time) and yes, replacing the draft inducer made it quiet again.